# How to use TimeAgo format with firestore or realtime database?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-dateutils

I am using a [Github Library](https://github.com/marlonlom/timeago) to Display time in a `TextView` as the format like just now, yesterday, time ago... etc. It displays the time as I want. But the problem is that the time is not changing as it was **just now** at the moment of post-it remains that forever.

Model class for **postAdapter**

```
class Post {
private var date: String = ""
constructor(date: Long) {
fun getDate(): String
    {
        return date
    }

   //Initialization according to the library
    val timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val timeAgo = TimeAgo.using(timeInMillis)


   //saving the data to firestore
    val fStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    val post = Post(title, description, date = timeAgo)
                    fStore.collection("Posts").document()
                            .set(post)
                            .addOnSuccessListener{...}
```

Retrieving the data from the `Firestore`

```
private fun postInfo(title: TextView, description: TextView, date: TextView) {
        val postRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Posts").document()
        postRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                    if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        val post = documentSnapshot.toObject(Post::class.java)
                        date.text = post?.getDate()
                        title.text = post?.getTitle()
                        description.text = post?.getDescription()
                    } 
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show how a screenshot to see how the date is stored in Firestore.

Comment: I update the question check please.

Comment: What does `post?.getDate()` return, that long value as a String, right?

Comment: yes @AlexMamo :(

Comment: It seems that you are still receiving a long value. Have you tried if you are able to further  convert “timeAgo” with “.ToString()”? In addition to that, does this date value correspond to the Firestore TimeStamp? Have you tried utilizing any other Library instead of this specific TimeAgo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is using a library to convert a date to a string, and then set the TextView text to that string. Strings are only lists of chars and they have no "consciousness" about what they mean or if they ever need to change/update.

I would suggest using a `RelativeTimeTextView` from `android-ago`. Once you set a reference time to that view, there's some code inside that will automatically trigger updates for you.

https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago

Edit: you're also doing conversion from `timeInMillis: Long` to `date: String` at the moment of storage in firestore. You should instead store timeInMillis as is (Long value) and then when reading use it as argument of `relativeTimetextView.setReferenceTime(timeInMillis)`.

Comment: I have used the you suggested but i was doing the same thing so please tell me that what should i do with that relative layout. i mean what should i do after that , how that view will show the time and change with time.

Comment: You should consider storing the `timeInMillis` without any conversion.

Comment: bro when i use long it shows me a long value as for just now 1590384536875.

Comment: can you share the code that uses `RelativeTimeTextView` please ?

Comment: I am not using that lib